# What is the true minimum duration for an AWS Transcribe input file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, transcription, amazon-transcribe

According to the AWS docs, it's 500 milliseconds: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/transcribe.html#limits-amazon-transcribe

But according to the error message I got from the service, it's 0.5 milliseconds:

```
"TranscriptionJobStatus": "FAILED",
"FailureReason": "The input media file length is too small. Minimum audio duration is 0.500000 milliseconds. Check the length of the file and try your request again.",
```

Is it just a mistake in the error message? (I'm guessing yes, since the file I uploaded was longer than 0.5ms but shorter than 500ms.)